# Constructing a table from multiple links in one

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to extract data from a website where I have pulled the list of urls where the data is hosted and I am able to pull the data but I am not able to pull it in table form.

I have tried in multiple codes, I extracted the href links then appended them into a list. I am using requests and beautiful soup libraries to extract data.

```
url = 'https://www.flinders.edu.au/directory/index.cfm/search/results?page=1&lastnamesearch=A&firstnamesearch=&ousearch='

for rows in df_link['Name']:
url = rows
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for table in soup.find_all('table', {'summary' : 'Staff list that match search criteria'}):
    n_columns = 0
    n_rows = 0
    column_names = []

    column_names = [th.get_text() for th in table.select('th')]
    n_columns = len(column_names)

    rows = table.select('tr')[1:]
    n_rows = len(rows)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names, index=range(n_rows))

    r_index = 0
    for row in rows:
        c_index = 0
        for cell in row.select('td'):
            anchor = cell.select_one('a')
            df.iat[r_index, c_index] = anchor.get('href') if anchor else cell.get_text()

            c_index += 1
        r_index += 1

    #c_index = 1
    #for nam in row.find_all('a', {'class' : 'directory directory-person'}):

     #   df.iat[r_index, c_index] = nam.get_text()

      #  c_index += 1
    #r_index += 1

    print(df)

urls = []
for row in df['Name\xa0⬆']:
   urls.append(link+row)

for url in urls:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    for name in soup.find_all('span' , {'class' : 'directory directory-entity'}):
        results['Name'] = table.text
    p = []
    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        position = row.find_all('td')
        p.append(position[0].text)
        results['Position'] = p[1]
        results['Phone'] = p[4]
        results['Email'] = p[9].replace('\n', '')
    print(results)
```

I am expecting the result in a table form. Assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following using pandas and BeautifulSoup 4.7.1.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

baseUrl = 'https://www.flinders.edu.au'

emails = []
positions = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.flinders.edu.au/directory/index.cfm/search/results?page=1&lastnamesearch=A&firstnamesearch=&ousearch=')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    names, urls = zip(*[ (item.text, baseUrl + item['href']) for item in soup.select('td:first-child a')])
    tels = [item.text for item in soup.select('td:nth-of-type(2) a')]

    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        positions.append(soup.select_one('.staffInfo + td').text)
        emails.append(soup.select_one('[href^=mailto]').text)

final = list(zip(names, tels, positions, emails))
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns = ['name', 'tel', 'position', 'email'])
print(df.head())
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

Sample output:

[image]

---

If you have problems with names and tels you can also do the following:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.flinders.edu.au/directory/index.cfm/search/results?page=1&lastnamesearch=A&firstnamesearch=&ousearch=')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    data =  [item.text for item in soup.select('.directory-person')]
    names = data[0::2]
    tels = data[1::2]
```

Comment: If I use the above code I get an error "Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type." if I use nth of type (1) I get only 1 output. Can you please assist?

Comment: is that occurring for you on  soup.select('td:first-child a') ? That can be re-written as td:nth-of-type(1) a

Comment: I am using bs4 latest version 4.7.1 btw

Comment: When I write it as  td:nth-of-type(1), it only outputs the first name. Also, I tried updating bs4 through pip but it says requirement already satisfied with version 4.6.3

Comment: 4.7.1 has soup sieve which allows for all the cool stuff but yes, your current version should support nth-of-type just fine.

Comment: you could also use .directory-person  and then extract [0::2] from the returned list to get the names

Comment: I am not sure why is this happening but I have updated my bs4 version to 4.7.1 and it still outputs only 1

Comment: you could also use: names = [item.text for item in soup.select('.directory-person')][0::2]    and tels =  [item.text for item in soup.select('.directory-person')][1::2]

Comment: So I am using anaconda with python version 3.7.1. and I have tried all the above and updated bs4 as well, still I get 1 output. I tried looping as well but it didnt work

Comment: Not sure as running from anaconda via notebook myself. Are you running exactly as per my code? Here is just first part https://pastebin.com/6AkWTWJp

Comment: Yes this did it, Thanks for your assistance